# Access or Mysql - Table rows as columns in query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, pivot

I have these three tables:

[image]

The table "Clienti" contains the customers.
The table "Corsi" contains all the available courses
The table "corsi Fatti" contains all the Courses each client has taken.

what I would need is a query that returns each client, and what courses he attended on what date.
For that I would like to have for example a table returned with these columns:

Clienti.Nome, corsi.row1.corso, corsi.row2.corso, corsi.row3.corso,corsi.rowN.corso.

and the content of the table should be:
clienti.Nome, corsifatti.data of the matching course in the corsi table if present.

so, first column is the client name, and then there is a column for each row of the "corsi" table, and if a client has partecipated on that course then the corsifatti.data should be in that column.

Can something like this be done with a Access or Mysql Query? I have tried with inner joins but the result was not what I need.

```
select
  Clienti.nome, Clienti.Addresse, Clienti.CAP, Clienti.Tel,
  Clienti.Ansprechpartner, Clienti.Mail, Clienti.Weiteres,
  CorsiFatti.Data, Corsi.Corso, Corsi.Durata 
from Clienti 
INNER JOIN CorsiFatti on CorsiFatti.[ID Cliente] = Clienti.ID 
INNER JOIN Corsi on Corsi.ID = CorsiFatti.[ID Corso]
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a simple inner join:

```
select Clienti.nome, Clienti.Addresse, Clienti.CAP, 
   Clienti.Tel, Clienti.Ansprechpartner, Clienti.Mail, 
   Clienti.Weiteres, 
   CorsiFatti.Data, 
   Corsi.Corso, Corsi.Durata 
from Clienti 
INNER JOIN CorsiFatti on CorsiFatti.[ID Cliente] = Clienti.ID 
INNER JOIN Corsi on Corsi.ID = CorsiFatti.[ID Corso]
order by Clienti.nome, Corsi.Corso;
```

I think you meant yours was lacking the order by only.
I wouldn't suggest using access, but if it is access anyway, then you need to have parenthseses around all those joins (peculiar I know, but it is access).

Comment: thank you for your time, but Im not sure that this is what I need. I'd need to have Corsi.corso as columns. so each ROW in corsi, is one column in the resultin query. and the value inside that column would be the date if there is a entry with the corresponding ID in corsifatti

Comment: That means a dynamic pivot. I wouldn't dare to write that for access. You can find dynamic pivot samples here for MS SQL Server. If you were using postgreSQL, then this could be a piece of cake using tablefunc extension. For an access user, it should be easier to take this data to excel via automation and transpose.

Answer (score 0):

The pivot with variable columns count is complicated. I can advice simplest solution uses JSON aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  ClienteId, 
  Name, 
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT("Data", Data, "Corso", Corso)
  ) Corsi 
FROM 
  CorsiFatti 
  JOIN Corsi ON Corsi.Id = CorsiFatti.CorsoId 
  JOIN Clienti ON Clienti.Id = CorsiFatti.clienteId 
GROUP BY 
  ClienteId, 
  Name
;
```

Result is row for each client contains client's data at his courses as JSON string:

```
+===========+=========+========================================================================================+
| ClienteId | Name    | Corsi                                                                                  |
+===========+=========+========================================================================================+
| 1         | Mr. Fix | [{"Data": "2021-01-01", "Corso": "Corso1"}, {"Data": "2021-02-01", "Corso": "Corso3"}] |
+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here you can find [SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=8f559fa000a6e7573536be3087ed2fbd&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)